# How to compare two lists row wise (1st row with 1st row,2nd row with 2nd row likewise)?

Tags: python

I have three list of index values

`indexval`

```
0 [3, 2, 7, 5]
1 [1]
2 [4, 1, 6, 2]
3 [2,3,1]
```

Then value list

`value`

```
0 [1]
1 [0]
2 [3]
3 [2]
```

What I want is,`indexval` should randomly select "n" number of values in each row.That "n" number should refer the `value` list so that i should get output like this.

```
0 [3]
1 [ ]
2 [1,2,4]
3 [1,2]
```

Can anyone help me with this...

Comment: You data does not look like it is in Python syntax.

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough. Please be more clear.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import random

LoL=[[3, 2, 7, 5],
    [1],
    [4, 1, 6, 2],
    [2,3,1]]

vals=[1,0,3,2]  
for x,sl in zip(vals,LoL):
    print [random.choice(sl) for _ in range(x)]
```

Or more concisely:

```
>>> ([[random.choice(sl) for _ in range(x)] for x,sl in zip(vals,LoL)])
[[3], [], [4, 6, 6], [3, 1]]
```

As stated in comments, you can also use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) if you do not want any values reused from the list or [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (Python 3.6+) if you want to add weightings to the section from the list.

Example with random.sample:

```
>>> [random.sample(sl, k) for k,sl in zip(vals,LoL)]
[[7], [], [6, 4, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Repeatedly calling `random.choice` may get the same value several times (as you can see with the doubled 6s in your example output in the concise version. It's not entirely clear if that's what the questioner wants or not (it doesn't happen in the example output in the question, but that could be just chance). Using just one call (per list) to `random.sample` will not pick the same value more than once, so it might be a better choice. I do like you use of `zip` however!

Answer (score 1):

Given the two *lists*. you can use `random.sample`.

***This randomly picks `k` unique items from a `population` sequence*** (*i.e. random sampling without replacement in stat. terms*):

```
import random

indexval = [[3, 2, 7, 5], [1], [4, 1, 6, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
value = [1, 0, 3, 2]

for i in range(len(indexval)):
    print(random.sample(population = indexval[i], k = value[i]))

[2]
[]
[1, 6, 4]
[1, 2]
```

To perform random sampling with replacement (*i.e. non unique items are allowed*) use `random.choices`, refer dawg's solution.